# Caching a table in SQL server database

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, caching

I have a data warehouse where a lot of values are stored as coded values.  Coded columns store a numeric value that relates to a row on the CODE_VALUE table. The row on the CODE_VALUE table contains descriptive information for the code. For example, the ADDRESS table has a Address_TYPE_CD column.Address type can be home/office/postal address etc . The output from selecting these columns would be a list of numbers as 121234.0/2323234.0/2321344.0. So we need to query the code_value table to get their descriptions.

We have created a function which hits the code_value table and gets the description for these codes. But when I use the function to change codes to their description it takes almost 15 minutes for a query that otherwise takes a few seconds . So I was thinking of loading the table permanently in Cache. Any suggestions how can this be dealt with??

A solution being used by another system is described below

I have been using Cerner to query the database, which uses User access routines to convert these code_values and are very quick. Generally they are written in C++. The routine is using the global code cache to look up the display value for the code_value that is passed to it.  That UAR never hits Oracle directly.  The code cache does pull the values from the Code_Value table and load them into memory.  So the code cache system is hitting Oracle and doing memory swapping to cache the code values, but the UAR is hitting that cached data instead of querying the Code_Value table.

EXAMPLE :

Person table

```
person_id(PK)
person_type_cd
birth_dt_cd
deceased_cd
race_cd
name
```

Visit table

```
visit_id(PK)
person_id(FK)
visit_type_cd
hospital_cd
visit_dt_tm
disch_dt_tm
reason_visit_cd
```

address code_value

```
address_id(PK)
person_id(FK)
address_type_cd
street
suburb_cd
state_cd
country_cd
```

code_value table

```
code_value
code_set
description
```

DATA :
code_value table

```
code_value    code_set     description

visit_type :
121212          12           admitted
122233          12           emergency
121233          12           outpatient

address_type :
1234434         233          home 
23234           233          office
343434          233          postal

ALTER function [dbo].[getDescByCv](@cv int)  
returns varchar(80)  

as begin   

-- Returns the code value display 

  declare @ret varchar(80)  
  select @ret = cv.DESCRIPTION
  from CODE_VALUE cv   
  where cv.code_value = @cv   
      and cv.active_ind = 1  
  return isnull(@ret, 0)

end;
```

Final query :

```
 SELECT 
   v.PERSON_ID as  PersonID 
   , v.ENCNTR_ID as EncntrID
   , [EMR_DWH].dbo.[getDispByCv](v.hospital_cd) as Hospital
   , [EMR_DWH].dbo.[getDispByCv](v.visit_type_cd) as VisitType

from visit v

SELECT 
   v.PERSON_ID as  PersonID 
   , v.ENCNTR_ID as EncntrID
   , [EMR_DWH].dbo.[getDispByCv](v.hospital_cd) as Hospital
   , [EMR_DWH].dbo.[getDispByCv](v.visit_type_cd) as VisitType
   , [EMR_DWH].dbo.[getDispByCv](n.person_type) as PersonType
   , [EMR_DWH].dbo.[getDispByCv](v.deceased_cd) as Deceased
   , [EMR_DWH].dbo.[getDispByCv](v.address_type_cd) as AddressType
   , [EMR_DWH].dbo.[getDispByCv](v.country_cd) as Country

from visit v
    ,person p
    ,address a

 where v.visit_id = 102288.0
  and v.person_id = p.person_id
  and p.person_id = a.person_id
```

Comment: Probably Dont want a function.  More Information would help - simple example schema - not all 100 combinations - simple.   Comment .. sounds like you have an Entity Attribute Value concept.   Are you using a formal Cube SSAS also or just Sql Server by itself.  Are you joining a single table with 5 column to the CODE_VALUE table 5 times - once for each column?

Comment: Yes, you can say that. The function just takes in the code_value and returns the description. and if I have to extract 5 fields,they all use the function. It will be extensively used so I need to find a solution as all the major fields are coded. I'll update the example schema in the question.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just joining on the Code_Value table directly? You can join to the one table as many times as you like using aliases.

Comment: Hi Tom, I have tried that but its even more slow!!!

Comment: No way it should be slower than your function calls, where each column is an additional query. Have you got the correct indexes set up? Post your version with joins as I suspect there might be some other problem. And please convert your join syntax to SQL92 version `join table on condition` instead of `from table1,table2`